# If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$ and if $g\geq c>0$ on $(a,\infty)$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[f\left(x+g(x)\right)-f(x)\right]=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

**Problem:** Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. Assume that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$. Prove that if $g\geq c>0$ on $(a,\infty)$, then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[f\left(x+g(x)\right)-f(x)\right]=0.$$

**My Thoughts:** Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. By hypothesis, there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\vert f'(x)\vert<\varepsilon$ for all $x>N$. Since $g\geq c>0$, it follows that $x+g(x)>N$ for all $x>N$. Fix $x>N$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[x,x+g(x)]$ and differentiable on $(x,x+g(x))$, the mean value threorem implies that there is some $u\in(x,x+g(x))$ such that
$$\left\vert\frac{f(x+g(x))-f(x)}{x+g(x)-x}\right\vert=\left\vert\frac{f(x+g(x))-f(x)}{g(x)}\right\vert=\vert f'(u)\vert<\varepsilon.$$
The above implies that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\vert f(x+g(x))-f(x)\vert}{g(x)}=0.$$
On the other hand, $1/g(x)\leq 1/c$, so that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\vert f(x+g(x))-f(x)\vert}{c}=0,$$
from which the result follows by the laws of limits.

---

Do you agree with my proof above?
Thank you for your help in advance.

Note: The last step is incorrect, ignore my attempted proof.

Comment: The proposition is false!

Comment: I think you should have $|g(x) |<c$ and not $g(x) >c$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proposition is false. The following is a counter-example.

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.
Then $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, differentiable on $(0,\infty)$,
and $f'(x)\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. Let $g:(1,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
be defined by $g(x)=x^{2}.$ For sufficiently large $x$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & f(x+g(x))-f(x)\\
 & = & \frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{x+x^{2}}+\sqrt{x}}\\
 & \rightarrow & \infty
\end{eqnarray*}
as $x\rightarrow\infty$.